# Tabulator V 5.0.10+ cellTap not working on Chromium based browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, tabulator

Taking the following js script:

```js
// Example function
function DoStuff(e, cell) {
    console.log("Do Stuff")
}

// Returning fontawesome icon
var Ico = function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) { return '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>' }

//Table
var Table= new Tabulator("#anchor", {
    data: [],
    layout: "fitColumns",
    pagination: "local",
    responsiveLayout: "collapse",
    movableRows: true,
    columns: [
        { title: "Name", field: "Name", headerFilter: true, headerSort: false },
        { title: "Code", field: "Code", headerFilter: true, headerSort: false },
        { title: `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`, headerSort: false, formatter: Ico, width: 25, hozAlign: "center", headerHozAlign: "center", cellClick: DoStuff, cellTap: DoStuff}
    ]
})
```

**Expected behavior**
On touch screens, X browser, cellTap should be called whenever a finger taps the table cell exactly as cellClick act when a click on the cell is performed.

**Real behavior**
On touch screens, Chromium based web browsers are not firing the Tap event and no js exception is thrown, tap event works as expected under Gecko based browsers

**Recap**
Docs (http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/callbacks#cell) does not report anywhere that Chromium based browser are not supported. Before opening an issue under Github i opened a question here cause i might be done something wrong. Tested browser are the followings:

- Firefox version 96.0.2 (64 bit) (Tap callback is working as expected, furthermore also cellClick works when a Tap is performed so cellTap is even useless)
- Chrome version 97.0.4692.99 (Official build) (64 bit) **TAP NOT WORKING**
- Edge version 44.18362.449.0 **TAP NOT WORKING**
- Opera version 83.0.4254.19 **TAP NOT WORKING**

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: New issue has been opened under github https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3588

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with version 5.0 and has been resolved in the 5.1 release